# Incorrect operand type error when using list_append function inside UpdateExpression

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to append a String to an existing StringSet in DynamoDB using the list_append function. Can anyone see what's wrong with this code? I've read and re-read the Amazon docs but can't seem to find the problem.

```
$this->objClient->updateItem( array(
        'TableName' => 'mytable',

        'Key' => array(
            'sEmailAddress' => array(
                'S' => 'somebody@email.com'
            )
        ),

        "ExpressionAttributeValues" => array(
            ':vServices' => array( 
                                "SS" => array( 
                                    'value to append'
                                )
                            )
        ),

        "ExpressionAttributeNames" => array(
            "#serv" => "sServices"
        ),

        'UpdateExpression' =>   'set #serv = list_append( #serv, :vServices )'

    ));
```

The error message generated is:

**Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: SS**

From what I'd read I thought both operands had to be StringSets. In vain I've tried changing the second parameter to be a single string (type 'S') but still experience the same kind error:

**Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: S**

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`list_append` operates on two lists. To add an item to a set, you can use the `ADD` operator instead of calling `SET` with the results of `list_append`.

Comment: Great, thanks - I hadn't quite grasped the fact that lists and sets were different!